# VueJS: Como compartilhar dados de um componentes para outro?

Tags: vue.js

Eu possuo dois componentes separados e preciso que ao clicar em um botão, ele modifique a variavel de outro componente.

Por exemplo eu tenho o seguinte componente:

```
var componenteFiltroBusca = new Vue({
     el: '#componenteFiltroBusca',
     data: {
        buscadorText: '(por n° de cupón, importe)',
     }
});
```

E quando eu clicar em um botão que está dentro do:

```
var tabMovimientos = new Vue({
    el: '#tabMovimientos',
})
```

Eu preciso que ele altere o texto dentro do *buscadorText*, como fazer isso?

Comment: Qual é a relação entre eles? Têm algum componente em comum? são descendentes?

Comment: eles não possuem nenhuma relação

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se os componentes não têm nenhuma relação podes criar um `$bus`, ou seja um canal via `Vue.prototype` e que todos os componentes podem usar para enviar e escutar eventos.

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue({});
```

e depois nos componentes podes fazer assim:

```
// para avisar o canal de eventos
this.$bus.$emit('increment', a, b, c);

// para receber eventos
this.$bus.$on('increment', function(a, b, c){
  // etc...
});
```

**Implementado:**

```js
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue({});
new Vue({
    el: '#botao',
    data: {
        count: 0
    },
    methods: {
        updateCount() {
            this.count++;
            this.$bus.$emit('increment', this.count);
        }
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#mostrador',
    data: {
        contador: 0,
    },
    created() {
        this.$bus.$on('increment', val => this.contador = val);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="botao">
    <button type="submit" @click="updateCount">
        Incrementar
    </button>
</div>
<div id="mostrador">
    {{contador}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem duas formas elegantes para fazer isso, ou você instancia o outro componente dentro do seu e passa os novos valores via props

Ou você usa Vuex para construir uma arquitetura direcional. Espero ter ajudado!